# How to update SelectListItem Selected value inside a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, selectlistitem

I have a `List<SelectListItem>` that holds campuses and each `SelectListItem.Text` is the name of the campus and  `SelectListItem.Value` is the campus id.

Then I have `List<string>` that holds some campuses ids.

I need to set the `Selected` property of the `SelectListItem` to `true` to all of the campuses that match a campus id in here `List<string>`

My code below only works if there is only one id in `List<string>`

```
List<SelectListItem> CampusesList = ...
...
List<string> campuses = GetCampusesIds(id);
foreach (string campus in campuses) {
    CampusesList.ForEach(x => { x.Selected = x.Value == campus; });
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `CampusesList.ForEach(x => x.Selected = campuses.Contains(x.Value));` instead of the foreach loop you've got

Comment: that works, thanks

Comment: The real question is why you would want to set the `Selected` property. If you have generated you view correctly using `@Html.ListBoxFor(), then there is no point since the `Selected` property is ignored (internally the method builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not creating lists, I'm creating checkboxes

Comment: `SelectListItem` is for use in a `DropDownListFor()` method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [List.Contains Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) to return true if a specific value is in that list.

```
CampusesList.ForEach(x => x.Selected = campuses.Contains(x.Value));
```